# Spring Boot JPA Error: Why am I not able to use Command Line Runner to persist an object to the database?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to simply persist an object into the database and then retrieve it to check that it has worked. I have had the same error for the past few days and I'm not sure what the issue is. I noticed that when I take the @Bean annotation out from in front of the demo function in Application.java, it doesn't error, but it also doesn't successfully persist to the database.

I attached all relevant files below.

This is my Data Object:

```
package dataObjects;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="LoadMethod")
public class LoadMethodDO {

    private String mediaId;
    private String activeInd;
    private String loadMethod;
    private String formatMapCd;
    private String detailTransactionReportInd;
    private String accountManaged;

    public LoadMethodDO(){}

    public LoadMethodDO(String mediaId, String loadMethod){
        this.mediaId = mediaId;
        this.loadMethod = loadMethod;
    }
    @Id
    @Column(name="Media_ID", length = 7)
    public String getMediaId() {
        return mediaId;
    }
    public void setMediaId(String mediaId) {
        this.mediaId = mediaId;
    }
    @Column(name="ActInd")
    public String getActiveInd() {
        return activeInd;
    }
    public void setActiveInd(String activeInd) {
        this.activeInd = activeInd;
    }
    @Column(name="LoadMthdCd")
    public String getLoadMethod() {
        return loadMethod;
    }
    public void setLoadMethod(String loadMethod) {
        this.loadMethod = loadMethod;
    }
    @Column(name="FormatMapCd")
    public String getFormatMapCd() {
        return formatMapCd;
    }
    public void setFormatMapCd(String formatter) {
        this.formatMapCd = formatter;
    }
    @Column(name="DtlTransRcdInd")
    public String getDetailTransactionReportInd() {
        return detailTransactionReportInd;
    }
    public void setDetailTransactionReportInd(String detailTransactionReportInd) {
        this.detailTransactionReportInd = detailTransactionReportInd;
    }
    @Column(name="AcctMngdInd")
    public String getAccountManaged() {
        return accountManaged;
    }
    public void setAccountManaged(String accountManaged) {
        this.accountManaged = accountManaged;
    }
}
```

This is my repository file:

```
package repositories;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import dataObjects.LoadMethodDO;

public interface LoadMethodRepository extends CrudRepository<LoadMethodDO, String>{

}
```

This is my Application file that should persist the object:

```
package testApplication;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

import dataObjects.LoadMethodDO;
import repositories.LoadMethodRepository;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableCaching
public class Application {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("*****************");
        SpringApplication.run(DBController.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner demo(LoadMethodRepository repository) {
        return (args) -> {
            // save
            repository.save(new LoadMethodDO("12345678", "1234567"));
            // fetch
            LoadMethodDO temp = repository.findOne("1234567");
            System.out.println(temp.getMediaId());

        };
    }

}
```

This is my error code:

```
*****************

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.3.6.RELEASE)

2016-08-02 09:12:07.024  INFO 29732 --- [           main] testApplication.Application              : Starting Application on LR90KLWJY with PID 29732 (C:\Users\vincni\git\consumer_load_method\bin started by vincni in C:\Users\vincni\git\consumer_load_method)
2016-08-02 09:12:07.040  INFO 29732 --- [           main] testApplication.Application              : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-08-02 09:12:07.055  INFO 29732 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@543e710e: startup date [Tue Aug 02 09:12:07 PDT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-08-02 09:12:07.102  WARN 29732 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'DBController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: repositories.LoadMethodRepository testApplication.DBController.lmr; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [repositories.LoadMethodRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
2016-08-02 09:12:07.118 ERROR 29732 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'DBController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: repositories.LoadMethodRepository testApplication.DBController.lmr; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [repositories.LoadMethodRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:760) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:306) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at testApplication.Application.main(Application.java:25) [bin/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: repositories.LoadMethodRepository testApplication.DBController.lmr; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [repositories.LoadMethodRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [repositories.LoadMethodRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted

2016-08-02 09:12:07.118  INFO 29732 --- [           main] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/C:/Users/vincni/git/consumer_load_method/bin/, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.apache.camel/camel-ftp/jars/camel-ftp-2.16.1.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.apache.camel/camel-core/bundles/camel-core-2.16.1.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-core/jars/jaxb-core-2.2.11.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl/jars/jaxb-impl-2.2.11.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/com.jcraft/jsch/jars/jsch-0.1.53.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/commons-net/commons-net/jars/commons-net-3.3.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/com.zaxxer/HikariCP/jars/HikariCP-2.4.7.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/jars/slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/jars/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter/jars/spring-boot-starter-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot/jars/spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework/spring-core/jars/spring-core-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework/spring-context/jars/spring-context-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework/spring-aop/jars/spring-aop-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/aopalliance/aopalliance/jars/aopalliance-1.0.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework/spring-beans/jars/spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework/spring-expression/jars/spring-expression-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/jars/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/jars/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/jars/logback-classic-1.1.7.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/ch.qos.logback/logback-core/jars/logback-core-1.1.7.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/jars/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.21.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/jars/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.21.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/jars/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.21.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.yaml/snakeyaml/bundles/snakeyaml-1.16.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-aop/jars/spring-boot-starter-aop-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.aspectj/aspectjweaver/jars/aspectjweaver-1.8.9.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/jars/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-jdbc/jars/tomcat-jdbc-8.0.36.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-juli/jars/tomcat-juli-8.0.36.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework/spring-jdbc/jars/spring-jdbc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework/spring-tx/jars/spring-tx-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/jars/hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.jboss.logging/jboss-logging/jars/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.jboss.logging/jboss-logging-annotations/jars/jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/jars/hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/dom4j/dom4j/jars/dom4j-1.6.1.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/xml-apis/xml-apis/jars/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.hibernate.common/hibernate-commons-annotations/jars/hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.5.Final.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/jars/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.javassist/javassist/bundles/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/antlr/antlr/jars/antlr-2.7.7.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.jboss/jandex/jars/jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/javax.transaction/javax.transaction-api/jars/javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa/jars/spring-data-jpa-1.9.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework.data/spring-data-commons/jars/spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework/spring-orm/jars/spring-orm-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework/spring-aspects/jars/spring-aspects-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.apache.camel/camel-jpa/jars/camel-jpa-2.10.0.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.apache.camel/camel-spring/bundles/camel-spring-2.10.0.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.apache.poi/poi/jars/poi-3.10.1.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/commons-codec/commons-codec/jars/commons-codec-1.5.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml/jars/poi-ooxml-3.10.1.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml-schemas/jars/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.10.1.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.apache.xmlbeans/xmlbeans/jars/xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/stax/stax-api/jars/stax-api-1.0.1.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/com.microsoft.sqlserver/sqljdbc4/jars/sqljdbc4-4.0.jar, file:/C:/ExternalJARS/ojdbc7.jar, file:/C:/Users/vincni/workspace/workspace_lmt/libraries/EclipseLink%202.5.2/eclipselink/jlib/eclipselink.jar, file:/C:/Users/vincni/workspace/workspace_lmt/libraries/EclipseLink%202.5.2/eclipselink/jlib/jpa/javax.persistence_2.1.0.v201304241213.jar, file:/C:/Users/vincni/workspace/workspace_lmt/libraries/EclipseLink%202.5.2/eclipselink/jlib/jpa/org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen_2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd.jar, file:/C:/Users/vincni/workspace/workspace_lmt/libraries/EclipseLink%202.5.2/eclipselink/jlib/jpa/org.eclipse.persistence.jpars_2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd.jar, file:/C:/Users/vincni/workspace/workspace_lmt/libraries/EclipseLink%202.5.2/eclipselink/jlib/moxy/com.sun.tools.xjc_2.2.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/vincni/workspace/workspace_lmt/libraries/EclipseLink%202.5.2/eclipselink/jlib/moxy/com.sun.xml.bind_2.2.0.v201004141950.jar, file:/C:/Users/vincni/workspace/workspace_lmt/libraries/EclipseLink%202.5.2/eclipselink/jlib/moxy/javax.activation_1.1.0.v201108011116.jar, file:/C:/Users/vincni/workspace/workspace_lmt/libraries/EclipseLink%202.5.2/eclipselink/jlib/moxy/javax.mail_1.4.0.v201005080615.jar, file:/C:/Users/vincni/workspace/workspace_lmt/libraries/EclipseLink%202.5.2/eclipselink/jlib/moxy/javax.xml.bind_2.2.0.v201105210648.jar, file:/C:/Users/vincni/workspace/workspace_lmt/libraries/EclipseLink%202.5.2/eclipselink/jlib/moxy/javax.xml.stream_1.0.1.v201004272200.jar]
```

Console message if I take @bean out from in front of the `demo` function. I thought it might be interesting to see, but I am almost 100% percent sure the bean should be there. It doesn't persist anything without it and every source I have seen online says to put the @bean annotation there:

```
*****************

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.3.6.RELEASE)

2016-08-02 09:41:56.284  INFO 34864 --- [           main] testApplication.Application              : Starting Application on LR90KLWJY with PID 34864 (C:\Users\vincni\git\consumer_load_method\bin started by vincni in C:\Users\vincni\git\consumer_load_method)
2016-08-02 09:41:56.300  INFO 34864 --- [           main] testApplication.Application              : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-08-02 09:41:56.347  INFO 34864 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@15bfd87: startup date [Tue Aug 02 09:41:56 PDT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-08-02 09:41:58.537  INFO 34864 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2016-08-02 09:41:58.538  INFO 34864 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2016-08-02 09:41:58.638  INFO 34864 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.11.Final}
2016-08-02 09:41:58.638  INFO 34864 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2016-08-02 09:41:58.638  INFO 34864 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2016-08-02 09:41:58.794  INFO 34864 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
2016-08-02 09:41:58.855  WARN 34864 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.d.i.StandardDialectResolver      : HHH000385: Unknown Microsoft SQL Server major version [12] using SQL Server 2000 dialect
2016-08-02 09:41:58.862  INFO 34864 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
2016-08-02 09:41:58.935  INFO 34864 --- [           main] o.h.h.i.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory    : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2016-08-02 09:41:59.013  INFO 34864 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
2016-08-02 09:41:59.013  INFO 34864 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
2016-08-02 09:41:59.013  INFO 34864 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000396: Updating schema
2016-08-02 09:41:59.013  INFO 34864 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000232: Schema update complete
2016-08-02 09:41:59.248  INFO 34864 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2016-08-02 09:41:59.259  INFO 34864 --- [           main] testApplication.Application              : Started Application in 3.326 seconds (JVM running for 3.833)
2016-08-02 09:41:59.261  INFO 34864 --- [       Thread-2] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@15bfd87: startup date [Tue Aug 02 09:41:56 PDT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-08-02 09:41:59.263  INFO 34864 --- [       Thread-2] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2016-08-02 09:41:59.263  INFO 34864 --- [       Thread-2] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your entity, repositories and applications are in different packages and you didn't mention spring boot to scan packages for entities and other configurations.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "repositories" }) 
@EntityScan(basePackages = { "dataObjects" })
public class Application
```

Note: By default it will scan the current and sub-directories of `SpringBootApplication` annotated class. If you keep all your entity and repositories (other components) in the sub packages of `SpringBootApplication` annotated class then you don't need to mention the packages names to scan.

Comment: That was it. Thank you!